# Pandas .loc without KeyError

Tags: pandas

```
>>> pd.DataFrame([1], index=['1']).loc['2']  # KeyError
>>> pd.DataFrame([1], index=['1']).loc[['2']]  # KeyError
>>> pd.DataFrame([1], index=['1']).loc[['1','2']]  # Succeeds, as in the answer below.
```

I'd like something that doesn't fail in either of

```
>>> pd.DataFrame([1], index=['1']).loc['2']  # KeyError
>>> pd.DataFrame([1], index=['1']).loc[['2']]  # KeyError
```

Is there a function like `loc` which gracefully handles this, or some other way of expressing this query?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Update for @AlexLenail comment**
It's a fair point that this will be slow for large lists. I did a little bit of more digging and [found](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.intersection.html?highlight=intersection#pandas.Index.intersection) that the `intersection` method is available for `Indexes` and columns. I'm not sure about the algorithmic complexity but it's much faster empirically.

You can do something like this.

```
good_keys = df.index.intersection(all_keys)
df.loc[good_keys]
```

Or like your example

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1], index=['1'])
df.loc[df.index.intersection(['2'])]
```

Here is a little experiment below

```
n = 100000

# Create random values and random string indexes
# have the bad indexes contain extra values not in DataFrame Index
rand_val = np.random.rand(n)
rand_idx = []
for x in range(n):
    rand_idx.append(str(x))

bad_idx = []
for x in range(n*2):
    bad_idx.append(str(x))

df = pd.DataFrame(rand_val, index=rand_idx)
df.head()

def get_valid_keys_list_comp():
    # Return filtered DataFrame using list comprehension to filter keys
    vkeys = [key for key in bad_idx if key in df.index.values]
    return df.loc[vkeys]

def get_valid_keys_intersection():
    # Return filtered DataFrame using list intersection() to filter keys
    vkeys = df.index.intersection(bad_idx)
    return df.loc[vkeys]

%%timeit 
get_valid_keys_intersection()
# 64.5 ms ± 4.53 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%%timeit 
get_valid_keys_list_comp()
# 6.14 s ± 457 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

**Original answer**

I'm not sure if pandas has a built-in function to handle this but you can use Python list comprehension to filter to valid indexes with something like this.

Given a DataFrame `df2`

```
           A    B       C   D    F
test    1.0 2013-01-02  1.0 3   foo
train   1.0 2013-01-02  1.0 3   foo
test    1.0 2013-01-02  1.0 3   foo
train   1.0 2013-01-02  1.0 3   foo
```

You can filter your index query with this

```
keys = ['test', 'train', 'try', 'fake', 'broken']
valid_keys = [key for key in keys if key in df2.index.values]
df2.loc[valid_keys]
```

This will also work for columns if you use `df2.columns` instead of `df2.index.values`

Comment: Despite the fact this works, is there no way to do this in pandas itself? This could be really expensive if you're looking at a big table and a big list (n**2)

Comment: @AlexLenail good thought; I spent a little time digging and found an alternative solution.

Comment: I wish there were a macro for `df.loc[df.index.intersection(list)]`

Answer (score 2):

I found an alternative (provided a check for df.empty is made beforehand). You could do something like this

df[df.index=='2'] -> returns either a dataframe with matched values or empty dataframe.

Comment: Seems like scanning columns would be considerably slower than a key:value index retrieval?

For a 112k row dataframe, seeing a operator comparison average time of about `508 µs`, while a try/except approach is considerably fastesr at about a `35.7 µs`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work fine for me. I'm running Python 3.5 with pandas version 0.20.3.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Create dataframe
data = {'distance': [0, 300, 600, 1000],
        'population': [4.8, 0.7, 6.4, 2.9]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['Alabama','Alaska','Arizona','Arkansas'])

keys = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Virginia']

# Create a subset of the dataframe.
df.loc[keys]
          distance  population
Alabama        0.0         4.8
Alaska       300.0         0.7
Arizona      600.0         6.4
Virginia       NaN         NaN
```

Or if you want to exclude the NaN row:

```
df.loc[keys].dropna()
          distance  population
Alabama        0.0         4.8
Alaska       300.0         0.7
Arizona      600.0         6.4
```

Comment: Yep, this solution works too but if you happen to have rows already with all `NaN` they will get dropped unintentionally.

Comment: I get a FutureWarning: 
"Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing label will raise
KeyError in the future, you can use .reindex() as an alternative."

Comment: @TalWeiss What version of pandas are you on?

Comment: @stevepastelan 0.24.2

Answer (score 1):

This page https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike has the solution:

`In [8]: pd.DataFrame([1], index=['1']).reindex(['2'])
Out[8]:
    0
2 NaN`

Answer (score 1):

Using the sample dataframe from @binjip's answer:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Create dataframe
data = {'distance': [0, 300, 600, 1000],
        'population': [4.8, 0.7, 6.4, 2.9]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['Alabama','Alaska','Arizona','Arkansas'])

keys = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Virginia']
```

Get matching records from the dataframe. **NB:** The dataframe index must be unique for this to work!

```py
df.reindex(keys)
```

```
          distance  population
Alabama        0.0         4.8
Alaska       300.0         0.7
Arizona      600.0         6.4
Virginia       NaN         NaN
```

If you want to omit missing keys:

```py
df.reindex(df.index.intersection(keys))
```

```
         distance  population
Alabama         0         4.8
Alaska        300         0.7
Arizona       600         6.4
```

Answer (score 1):

There's [`get`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.get.html) which allows you to supply a default value in case the key isn't found.

```py
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame([1], index=['1']).get('2', "default") 
Out[1]: 'default'
pd.DataFrame([1], index=['1']).get(['2'], "default") 
Out[2]: 'default'
```

Answer (score 0):

df.loc uses index (values from df.index) not the position of the row. Did you mean to use .iloc instead

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33797580)