# How to (idiomatically) use pandas .loc to return an empty dataframe when key is not in index

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Say I have a DataFrame (with a multi-index, for that matter), and I wish to take the values at some index - but, if that index does not exist, I wish for it to return an empty df instead of a `KeyError`.

I've searched for similar questions, but they are all about pandas returning an empty dataframe when it is not desired at some cases (conversely, I do desire an empty dataframe in return).

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(1,1),(1,2),(3,1)]), 
                  columns=['a','b'], data=[[1,2],[3,4],[10,20]])
```

so, df is:

```
        a   b
1   1   1   2
    2   3   4
3   1   10  20
```

and `df.loc[1]` is:

```
    a   b
1   1   2
2   3   4
```

`df.loc[2]` raises a `KeyError`, and I'd like something that returns

```
    a   b
```

The closest I could get is by calling `df.loc[idx:idx]` as a slice, which gives the correct result for `idx`=2, but for `idx`=1 it returns

```
        a   b
1   1   1   2
    2   3   4
```

instead of the desires result.

Of course I can define a function to do it,

Comment: if you want a pandas solution you could open the source code and take out the method under `index/base.py` and patch it for your use case `except KeyError:   return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))`

Comment: This would help if you are open to another option like - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46305796

Comment: @DishinHGoyani Thank you for your reference; I'll flag my question as a duplicate of that.

Answer (score 1):

One idea with `if-else` statament:

```
def get_val(x):
    return df.loc[x] if x in df.index.levels[0] else pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
```

Or generally with `try-except` statement:

```
def get_val(x):
    try:
        return df.loc[x]
    except KeyError:
        return pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
```

---

```
print (get_val(1))
   a  b
1  1  2
2  3  4

print (get_val(2))
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b]
Index: []
```

Comment: Yes, this is a possible solution; I'm hoping for a pandonic solution, but if all else fails I can define a function.

Comment: Also, if we're using `try`/`expect`, I'd `except` a `KeyError`

Comment: @ItamarMushkin - I think no such parameter in `loc` for processing non existing values.