# How to get multiple labels in Pandas 1.1.2?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a script that worked fine as long as I did not upgraded Pandas (0.24 --> 1.1.2). I have to select a list of dates from a dataframe, which has a multiindex that includes dates and products and the columns are the metrics.

So far i have done this and it worked liked a charm: `df.loc[selected_dates]`
Where `selected_dates` is the list of dates. Some dates may be missing, and it's okay, because nan values will be dropped.

Now I have to sacrifice a goat figuratively to achieve the same with [the method suggested by the guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-with-list-with-missing-labels-is-deprecated) (using reindexing) and it is still prone to errors.

How can I **simply** get these rows again with the new API?

Here's a sample data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
from random import randint

selected_dates = ['2020-09-02', '2020-09-05', '2020-09-10']

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([pd.date_range('2020-09-01', '2020-09-07'), ['prod1', 'prod2', 'prod3']])
metric1 = [i for i in range(len(idx))]
metric2 = [10*i for i in range(len(idx))]
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(metric1=metric1, metric2=metric2), index=idx)

df.loc[selected_dates] # KeyError
```

The `df` data frame will look like this:

```
                  metric1  metric2
2020-09-01 prod1        0        0
           prod2        1       10
           prod3        2       20
2020-09-02 prod1        3       30
           prod2        4       40
           prod3        5       50
...
```

Please think in big! These frame are quite large, and selection is done many times.
I have already looked at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46305796/pandas-loc-without-keyerror/46307319), but it's rather relevant for single indices, not multiindex.

Any hints are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) use converted values to datetimes for match, then use `IndexSlice` with first `:` for match all values in second level of `MultiIndex` and second `:` for match all columns:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice

selected_dates = pd.to_datetime(selected_dates)
df = df.loc[idx[selected_dates,:], :] 
print (df)
                  metric1  metric2
2020-09-02 prod1        3       30
           prod2        4       40
           prod3        5       50
2020-09-05 prod1       12      120
           prod2       13      130
           prod3       14      140
```

Or use [`Index.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) with [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
selected_dates = pd.to_datetime(selected_dates)
df = df[df.index.get_level_values(0).isin(selected_dates)]
print (df)
                  metric1  metric2
2020-09-02 prod1        3       30
           prod2        4       40
           prod3        5       50
2020-09-05 prod1       12      120
           prod2       13      130
           prod3       14      140
```

Comment: I wasn't aware that such IndexSlice thing exists. I was looking for that. The user guide barely mentions it. Thanks a lot!
I knew get_level_values, but that did not qualified as being simple, though it's also a valid solution. It's a returning use case for me, so simplicity is key to develop best practice with this new version.