# dictionary-like get() method for rows of a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a better, more idiomatic way to do this?

```
import pandas as pd
df : pd.DataFrame

try:
   row = df.loc[key]
except KeyError:
   row = None
```

If I wanted a column instead of a row I could just use `df.get(key)`.    I tried `df.transpose().get(key)`, which does work, but the transpose is not just a view, it physically transposes the data so it is quite slow when used for this purpose.

Comment: Rows have numbered indexes by default. Use `df.iloc[0]` to get 1st row.

Comment: I'd think this is more idiomatic: `df.loc[key] if key in df.index else None`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas .loc without KeyError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46305796/pandas-loc-without-keyerror)

Comment: Using `try-except` like this *is idiomatic*. Just wrap it in a function if you are going to do it many times.

Answer (score 2):

Use `reindex`, but that would return a series of `NaN`:

```
df.reindex([key]).loc[key]
```

Comment: this cannot be an efficient way to accomplish this. The most efficient and idiomatic way would be to just use `try-except`.